# SQL Subquery: Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I try to get the total duration of course offerings from a certain teacher, as well as the total duration of course offerings given in the hometown of the certain teacher. I use the next query:

```
SELECT SUM(dur) AS 'Totaal', (SELECT SUM(dur) 
                              FROM dept d INNER JOIN emp e
                              ON e.deptno = d.deptno
                              WHERE d.loc = o.loc
                              GROUP BY trainer) AS 'In eigen stad'
FROM offr o INNER JOIN crs c
ON o.course = c.code
GROUP BY trainer, o.loc
```

The problem is it gives the next error msg:

> 'Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.'

Any idea why?

---

```
SELECT SUM(dur) AS Totaal, (SELECT SUM(dur) 
                            WHERE o.trainer = e.empno
                            AND d.loc = o.loc) AS [In eigen stad]
FROM offr o INNER JOIN crs c
ON o.course = c.code
INNER JOIN dept d 
ON o.loc = d.loc
INNER JOIN emp e
ON o.trainer = e.empno
GROUP BY trainer, o.loc
```

Comment: You are grouping by `trainer`, but not selecting it in the column list.   Why?   Same with `o.loc` in the outer query.

Comment: Please post the schema (as `CREATE TABLE` statements)  or at least fully qualify all columns, so that we can see to which table they belong to. I suspect `trainer` is not a column of `dept` nor `emp`.

Comment: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-164.aspx

Comment: Can't put multi-row result in `SELECT`

Answer (score 0):

You don't want `group by` in the subquery.  You want a correlated subquery.  Without sample data and desired results, it is a bit hard to tell what you exactly want calculated, but I think it is:

```
SELECT SUM(dur) AS Totaal,
       (SELECT SUM(dur) 
        FROM dept d INNER JOIN
             emp e
             ON e.deptno = d.deptno
        WHERE d.loc = o.loc 
      ) AS [In eigen stad]
FROM offr o INNER JOIN
     crs c
     ON o.course = c.code
GROUP BY trainer, o.loc
```

Comment: Yes that helped a lot! 
I changed my query around a bit, but now i get the message: 
'Column 'emp.empno' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause'.
And,
'Column 'dept.loc' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.'
See the query in the question erea

Comment: @JonathanVandionant, why did you change query to new updated one? The SQL in the answer above should work for you to return counts by Hometown and Trainer.

Comment: No it didn't, because the subselect returned multiple values

Comment: @JonathanVandionant, can you post sample data , I doubt it returned multiple values if you used exact same subselect.

Comment: @JonathanVandionant . . . The subquery in this answer *cannot* return multiple values.  It is an aggregation query with no `group by`, so the subquery *always* returns exactly one row.